# Getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' while running the script on mobile browser

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am using:

1. selenium 3.0.0
2. Appium : 1.7.2

**Requirement:** Scroll in the mobile browser and click the button which will open new url.

**Code:**

```
Point loc =Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='button']")).getLocation(); 

System.out.println(loc);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)Driver;
js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(0,"+loc.y+")"); 
Thread.sleep(4000);
//Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
//actions.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP).perform();
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id='button']")).click();
```

**Getting exception:**

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
>   at this line : js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(0,"+loc.y+")");

**Note:** but element is scrolled to that point

Comment: Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try this - `js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+loc.getLocation().getY();+")");`

Comment: @ Sudha Velan  i m getting syntax error

Comment: Sorry.I thought its web element..Can you try this one - `js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+loc.getY();+")"); `

Comment: i have edited and  tried :js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+loc.getY()+")");   ---with reference to your suggestion but still getting same error

Comment: getting error The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String in the syntax so edited like js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+loc.getY()+")"); but still the error is same :(

Comment: @SudhaVelan anything else which you want me to try?

Comment: This should work actually..Can you cross check the browser version with selenium version.That they are compatible to each other.